# How do I change the text of a <tspan> dynamically?

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I change the text of a `<tspan>`?

I tried `.innerText =`, and I looked at all of the properties that Chrome offers on the element, and I can't find anything that helps me update the text.

I would like a vanilla javascript implementation, not one that is based on jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried `.textContent = "test text"` yet? Remember that SVGs are an implantation of XML, not HTML and thus not all DOM properties/methods will overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `el.textContent = 'my text';`.

Comment: This is expanded on at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score 0):

alternatively:

```
document.querySelector('tspan').innerHTML = 'new text';
```

Comment: This does appear to work as well, nice! Just be careful because the payload is rendered as HTML rather than text. This can open security holes depending how the dynamic content is sourced.

Comment: @Brandon, not exactly, at least not in `Chrome Version 100.0.4896.60` (my current browser), it does seem like the browser sanitizes any sort of HTML tags, i.e. including even `<br/>` tag, so it's safe to say that there shouldn't be any concerns about the security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for letting me know that.